# How to build re-usable scikit-learn pipeline for Random Forest Classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand how scikit-learn pipelines work. I have some dummy data and I am trying to fit a Random Forest model to iris data. Here is some code

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import sklearn.externals
import joblib
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
# Load the Iris dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

Divide data into train and test and create a pipeline with 2 steps

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target,random_state=0)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
pipeline = Pipeline([('feature_selection', SelectKBest(chi2, k=2)), ('classification', RandomForestClassifier()) ])
print(type(pipeline))
(112, 4) (38, 4) (112,) (38,)
<class 'sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline'>
```

But when i execute `pipeline.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)` , I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'transform'`

However, `pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)` works fine.

In a normal case scenario, without any `pipeline` code, what i have usually done is taken a ML model and applied `fit_transform()` on my `training` dataset and `transform` on my `unseen dataset` for generating predictions.

How do I set something similar using pipelines in `sklearn`. I want to SAVE my pipeline and then perform scoring by LOADING it back? Can I do it using `pickle`?

Another thing is regarding the RF model itself. I can get model summary using RF model methods but I dont see any methods in my pipeline where I can print model summary using `pipeline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when i execute `pipeline.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)`, I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'transform'`

Indeed, `RandomForestClassifier` does not `transform` data because it is a model, not a transformer.  Pipelines implement either `transform` or `predict` (and its variants) depending on whether the last estimator is a transformer or a model.

So, generally, you'll want to call just `pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)`, then in testing or production you'll call `pipeline.predict(X_test, y_test)` (or `predict_proba`, or ...), which internally will `transform` with the first step(s) and `predict` with the last step.

> How do I set something similar using pipelines in sklearn. I want to SAVE my pipeline and then perform scoring by LOADING it back? Can I do it using pickle?

Yes; see [sklearn Model Persistence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) for more details and recommendations.

> Another thing is regarding the RF model itself. I can get model summary using RF model methods but I dont see any methods in my pipeline where I can print model summary using pipeline.

You can access individual steps of a pipeline in a few ways; see [sklearn Pipeline accessing steps](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#accessing-steps)

```py
pipeline.named_steps.classification
pipeline['classification']
pipeline[-1]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it makes sense now. On a similar note, can i perhaps utilize this `pipeline` feature by sklearn for doing multiple types of transformations on different columns ? So if I have 1 categorical variable which I want to one hot encode, 1 numeric which I want to standardize, is there  a way to do to this diff transformations on diff columns using pipelines? Any examples would be really helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: That's what `ColumnTransformer` is for.